# How to do correct Repository factory?

Tags: angularjs, typescript

i have some free days between projects so i decided to learn `typescript`.
Therefore i want to do a repository factory. The idea is simple, there is some `API` where i can access `models` crud actions. It is nice solution to have one `generic` `repository` for buisnes models. But still get the `model` class from `CRUD` methods.

What is the correct way to do it ? Can someone help me solve this? How to do it right ?

What i want to achive is:

```
var factory = new RepositoryFactory($resource, 'http://api.com');
var repo = factory.getRepository(User);
var user = repo.getAll();
```

I starded to do somethink like this:

`IEntity`:

```
'use strict';

export interface IEntity {
    id: number;
}
```

`IRepository`:

```
'use strict';

import {IEntity} from "./IEntity";

export interface IRepository<T extends IEntity> {
    getAll(params:Object): T[];
    getById(id:number): T;
    create(data:Object): T;
    update(id:number, data:{id:number}): T;
    remove(id:number): boolean;
}
```

`RepositoryFactory`

```
'use strict';

import {IEntity} from "./IEntity";
import {Repository} from "./Repository";

export default class RepositoryFactory {
    protected $resource:any;
    protected url:string;

    constructor($resource:any, url:string) {
        this.$resource = $resource;
        this.url = url;
    }

    public getRepository<T extends IEntity>(model:T):Repository {
        return new Repository(this.$resource, this.url, model)
    }
}

`Repository`:
'use strict';

import {IRepository} from "./IRepository";
import {IEntity} from "./IEntity";

export default class Repository<T extends IEntity> implements IRepository<T> {
    protected $resource:any;
    protected resource:any;
    protected url:string;
    protected model:T;

    constructor($resource:any, url:string, model:T) {
        this.$resource = $resource;
        this.url = url;
        this.model = model;
        this.resource = this.getResource(model.path);
    }

    getAll(params:Object):T[] {
        let results = this.resource.query((typeof params === 'undefined' ? {} : params), this.onSuccess);

        return this.returnPromise(results);
    }

    getById(id:number):T {
        let model = this.resource.get({id: id}, this.onSuccess);

        return this.returnPromise(model);
    }

    create(data:Object):T {
        let model = new this.resource(data);

        return model.$save().then(this.onSuccess);
    }

    update(id:number, data:Object):T {
        data.id = id;
        var model = new this.resource(data);

        return model.$update().then(this.onSuccess);
    }

    remove(id:number):boolean {
        var data = {id: id};
        var model = new this.resource(data);

        return model.$delete().then(this.onSuccess);
    }

    protected getResource(path:string) {
        return this.$resource(this.url + path, {id: '@id'}, {
            'update': {
                method: 'PUT'
            },
            'get': {
                method: 'GET'
            },
            'save': {
                method: 'POST'
            },
            'query': {
                method: 'GET'
            },
            'remove': {
                method: 'DELETE'
            },
            'delete': {
                method: 'DELETE'
            }
        });
    }

    protected onSuccess(response:any) {
        if (this.checkPropertyExistence(response, 'data')) {
            if (response.data instanceof Array) {
                let results = response.data;
                for (var key in results) {
                    if (results.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                        results[key] = new this.model(results[key]);
                    }
                }

                return results;
            } else {
                return new this.model(response.data);
            }
        }

        return response;
    }

    protected transformRequest(obj:Object) {
        var str = [];
        for (var p in obj) {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
                str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
            }
        }

        return str.join("&");
    }

    protected returnPromise(object:Object) {
        return object.$promise.then(function (result) {
            return result;
        });
    }

    protected checkPropertyExistence(obj:Object, paths:string|string[]) {
        for (var i = 0; i < paths.length; i++) {
            if (!obj || !obj.hasOwnProperty(paths[i])) {
                return false;
            }
            obj = obj[paths[i]];
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

`User`:

```
'use strict';

import {IEntity} from "./IEntity";

export default class User implements IEntity {
    id:number;
    name:string;

    static _path:string = '/users';

    constructor(id:number, name:string) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    static get path():string {
        return this._path;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey guys i have menage to created working example for you.
The example shows how to create repository factory with `typescript`.

I have prepared this [DEMO FIDDLE](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=interface%20IEntity%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20id%3A%20number%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20Entity%20implements%20IEntity%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20private%20_id%3Anumber%3B%0A%20%20%20%20private%20_name%3Astring%3B%0A%20%20%20%20private%20_birth%3ADate%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(parameters%3A%20%7Bid%3Anumber%2C%20name%3Astring%2C%20birth%3ADate%7D)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this._id%20%3D%20parameters.id%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this._name%20%3D%20parameters.name%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this._birth%20%3D%20parameters.birth%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20get%20id()%3Anumber%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this._id%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20set%20id(value%3Anumber)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this._id%20%3D%20value%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20get%20name()%3Astring%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this._name%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20set%20name(value%3Astring)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this._name%20%3D%20value%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20get%20birth()%3ADate%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this._birth%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20set%20birth(value%3ADate)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this._birth%20%3D%20value%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20RepositoryFactory%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20public%20getRepository%3CT%20extends%20IEntity%3E(path%3Astring%2C%20model%3Astring)%3AIRepository%3CT%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20new%20Repository%3CT%3E(path%2C%20model)%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Ainterface%20IRepository%3CT%20extends%20IEntity%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20getAll(params%3AObject)%3A%20T%5B%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20getById(id%3Anumber)%3A%20T%3B%0A%20%20%20%20create(data%3AObject)%3A%20T%3B%0A%20%20%20%20update(id%3Anumber%2C%20data%3A%7Bid%3Anumber%7D)%3A%20T%3B%0A%20%20%20%20remove(id%3Anumber)%3A%20boolean%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20Repository%3CT%20extends%20IEntity%3E%20implements%20IRepository%3CT%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20protected%20path%3Astring%3B%0A%20%20%20%20protected%20model%3Astring%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(path%3Astring%2C%20model%3Astring)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.path%20%3D%20path%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.model%20%3D%20model%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20getAll(params%3AObject)%3AT%5B%5D%20%7B%0A%09%09let%20results%20%3D%20%5B%0A%09%09%09%7Bid%3A1%2C%20name%3A%20'rafal'%2C%20birth%3Anew%20Date()%7D%2C%0A%09%09%09%7Bid%3A2%2C%20name%3A%20'szymon'%2C%20birth%3Anew%20Date()%7D%2C%0A%09%09%09%7Bid%3A3%2C%20name%3A%20'mateusz'%2C%20birth%3Anew%20Date()%7D%2C%0A%09%09%5D%3B%0A%09%09%0A%09%09let%20entities%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0A%09%09for%20(var%20key%20in%20results)%20%7B%0A%09%09%09if%20(results.hasOwnProperty(key))%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09let%20entity%20%3D%20Object.create(window%5Bthis.model%5D.prototype)%3B%0A%09%09%09%09entity.constructor.apply(entity%2C%20new%20Array(results%5Bkey%5D))%3B%0A%09%09%09%09entities.push(entity)%3B%0A%09%09%09%7D%0A%09%09%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20entities%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20getById(id%3Anumber)%3AT%20%7B%0A%09%09let%20object%20%3D%20%7Bid%3Aid%2C%20name%3A%20'test'%2C%20birth%3Anew%20Date()%7D%3B%0A%09%09%0A%09%09var%20entity%20%3D%20Object.create(window%5Bthis.model%5D.prototype)%3B%0A%09%09entity.constructor.apply(entity%2C%20new%20Array(object))%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20entity%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20create(data%3AObject)%3AT%20%7B%09%09%0A%09%09var%20entity%20%3D%20Object.create(window%5Bthis.model%5D.prototype)%3B%0A%09%09entity.constructor.apply(entity%2C%20new%20Array(data))%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20entity%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20update(id%3Anumber%2C%20data%3AObject)%3AT%20%7B%0A%09%09var%20entity%20%3D%20Object.create(window%5Bthis.model%5D.prototype)%3B%0A%09%09entity.constructor.apply(entity%2C%20new%20Array(data))%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20entity%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20remove(id%3Anumber)%3Aboolean%20%7B%0A%09%09return%20true%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Avar%20factory%20%3D%20new%20RepositoryFactory()%3B%0Avar%20repo%20%3D%20factory.getRepository('%2Fusers'%2C%20'Entity')%3B%0A%0Avar%20users%20%3D%20repo.getAll(%7B%7D)%3B%0A%0Avar%20button%20%3D%20document.createElement('button')%3B%0Abutton.innerText%20%3D%20%22show%20users%22%3B%0Abutton.onclick%20%3D%20function()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(users)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Adocument.body.appendChild(button)%3B) where you can press `RUN` on the right side, and the page with single button will appear. After clicking the button `console.log` will display `getAll` method `results`.

In example i have mocked data, simply to show that factory works. If anyone wants to improves it, feel free and welcome to do it!

How it works?

```
//create factory, you can do it in an abstract controller class
//and later extends controller by it so you can easy get access to repository
var factory = new RepositoryFactory();
//inject path for $resource (unused in example)
//and your model.entity namespace
var repo = factory.getRepository('/users', 'User');

//call repo method
var users = repo.getAll({});
```

When using angular create `RepositoryFactory` as a `service`. Thats all. You may also want to inject `$resource` to get the right data from `API`.

And here is a full example code:

```
interface IEntity {
    id: number;
}

class Entity implements IEntity {
    private _id:number;
    private _name:string;
    private _birth:Date;

    constructor(parameters: {id:number, name:string, birth:Date}) {
        this._id = parameters.id;
        this._name = parameters.name;
        this._birth = parameters.birth;
    }

    get id():number {
        return this._id;
    }

    set id(value:number) {
        this._id = value;
    }

    get name():string {
        return this._name;
    }

    set name(value:string) {
        this._name = value;
    }

    get birth():Date {
        return this._birth;
    }

    set birth(value:Date) {
        this._birth = value;
    }
}

class RepositoryFactory {
    public getRepository<T extends IEntity>(path:string, model:string):IRepository<T> {
        return new Repository<T>(path, model)
    }
}

interface IRepository<T extends IEntity> {
    getAll(params:Object): T[];
    getById(id:number): T;
    create(data:Object): T;
    update(id:number, data:{id:number}): T;
    remove(id:number): boolean;
}

class Repository<T extends IEntity> implements IRepository<T> {
    protected path:string;
    protected model:string;

    constructor(path:string, model:string) {
        this.path = path;
        this.model = model;
    }

    getAll(params:Object):T[] {
        let results = [
            {id:1, name: 'rafal', birth:new Date()},
            {id:2, name: 'szymon', birth:new Date()},
            {id:3, name: 'mateusz', birth:new Date()},
        ];

        let entities= [];
        for (var key in results) {
            if (results.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                let entity = Object.create(window[this.model].prototype);
                entity.constructor.apply(entity, new Array(results[key]));
                entities.push(entity);
            }
        }

        return entities;
    }

    getById(id:number):T {
        let object = {id:id, name: 'test', birth:new Date()};

        var entity = Object.create(window[this.model].prototype);
        entity.constructor.apply(entity, new Array(object));

        return entity;
    }

    create(data:Object):T {     
        var entity = Object.create(window[this.model].prototype);
        entity.constructor.apply(entity, new Array(data));

        return entity;
    }

    update(id:number, data:Object):T {
        var entity = Object.create(window[this.model].prototype);
        entity.constructor.apply(entity, new Array(data));

        return entity;
    }

    remove(id:number):boolean {
        return true;
    }
}

var factory = new RepositoryFactory();
var repo = factory.getRepository('/users', 'Entity');

var users = repo.getAll({});
```